# How to efficiently fan out large chunks of data into multiple concurrent sub-processes in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

[I'm using Python 3.5.2 (x64) in Windows.]

I'm reading binary data in large blocks (on the order of megabytes) and would like to efficiently share that data into 'n' concurrent Python sub-processes (each process will deal with the data in a unique and computationally expensive way).

The data is read-only, and each sequential block will not be considered to be "processed" until all the sub-processes are done.

I've focused on shared memory (Array (locked / unlocked) and RawArray): Reading the data block from the file into a buffer was quite quick, but copying that block to the shared memory was noticeably slower.

With queues, there will be a lot of redundant data copying going on there relative to shared memory. I chose shared memory because it involved one copy versus 'n' copies of the data).

Architecturally, how would one handle this problem efficiently in Python 3.5?

**Edit: I've gathered two things so far: memory mapping in Windows is cumbersome because of the pickling involved to make it happen, and `multiprocessing.Queue` (more specifically, `JoinableQueue`) is faster though not (yet) optimal.**

**Edit 2: One other thing I've gathered is, if you have lots of jobs to do (particularly in Windows, where spawn() is the only option and is costly too), creating long-running parallel processes is better than creating them over and over again.**

Suggestions - preferably ones that use `multiprocessing` components - are still very welcome!

Comment: [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) may be of an interest if you can get your data into dask.bag objects

Comment: I'll look at that, but I'm curious about how to accomplish this with Python and `multiprocessing` in particular.

Comment: Is this data in a file where each subprocess could read its own chunk? That would eliminate the need for shared memory, at least on the data source side.

Comment: It'd be a lot of duplicated reading, which defeats the purpose here (each subprocess is working on all of the same source data).

Comment: What pickling?  each subprocess can mmap the file, and the parent can communicate with them using a queue (sending block offsets and receiving completion status). That seems about as efficient as you are likely to get.

Comment: `multiprocessing.Array` and such use pickling on Windows - I will give mmap a look though... might serve the purpose! Edit: I'm not positive about the pickling or if it's the problem, but `multiprocessing.Array` was super slow versus Queues.

Comment: I've made progress (if by progress one means "you probably can't do that in Python")... mmap looked promising but it only helps if it's in-memory only (e.g., anonymous memory) - and since you can't pickle mmap objects you can't spawn() them (since Windows doesn't fork()). If my project wasn't cross-platform this wouldn't be an issue, but it is so. There *might* be a way to create some kind of shared memory with cython, but it may be as much of a dead-end as mmap for this. In short, this may be as good as it gets within the language - wrong hammer for the job perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unix this might be tractable because fork() is used for multiprocessing, but in Windows the fact that spawn() is the only way it works really limits the options. However, this is meant to be a multi-platform solution (which I'll use mainly in Windows) so I am working within that constraint.

I could open the data source in each subprocess, but depending on the data source that can be expensive in terms of bandwidth or prohibitive if it's a stream. That's why I've gone with the read-once approach.

Shared memory via `mmap` and an anonymous memory allocation seemed ideal, but to pass the object to the subprocesses would require pickling it - but you can't pickle `mmap` objects. So much for that.

Shared memory via a cython module might be impossible or it might not but it's almost certainly prohibitive - and begs the question of using a more appropriate language to the task.

Shared memory via the shared `Array` and `RawArray` functionality was costly in terms of performance.

Queues worked the best - but the internal I/O due to what I think is pickling in the background is prodigious. However, the performance hit for a small number of parallel processes wasn't too noticeable (this may be a limiting factor on faster systems though).

I will probably re-factor this in another language for a) the experience! and b) to see if I can avoid the I/O demands the Python Queues are causing. Fast memory caching between processes (which I hoped to implement here) would avoid a lot of redundant I/O.

While Python is widely applicable, no tool is ideal for every job and this is just one of those cases. I learned a lot about Python's `multiprocessing` module in the course of this!

**At this point it looks like I've gone as far as I can go with standard CPython, but suggestions are still welcome!**